# .NET Excel Interop add object for VBA use

Tags: c#, .net, excel-interop

I am trying to add an object into excel so that it can be accessed via VBA Macros directly.

Both single objects and List

Is there any way to achieve this?

```
class Program
{
    public class Account
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public double Balance { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        // Create a list of accounts.
        var bankAccounts = new List<Account> {
            new Account {
                ID = 345678,
                Balance = 541.27
            },
            new Account {
                ID = 1230221,
                Balance = -127.44
            }
        };

        var excelApp = new Excel.Application
        {
            Visible = true
        };

        var workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();


        var workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;
    }
}
```

I know I can do something like the following, but would ideally like to just add an object into excel "ApplicationContext" so that it can be access from VBA rather than writing macro's to read all columns/rows.

```
workSheet.Range["A1"].Value = "ID";
workSheet.Range["B1"].Value = "Balance";

excelApp.Range["A2"].Select();

foreach (var account in bankAccounts)
{
    DisplayBankAccount(account, excelApp.ActiveCell);
    excelApp.ActiveCell.Offset[1, 0].Select();
}

void DisplayBankAccount(Account account, Excel.Range cell)
{
    cell.Value = account.ID;
    cell.Offset[0, 1].Value = account.Balance;
}
```

Comment: Probably. But you have not provided enough info nor made any attempt at code. Develop some code and when you have some with specific issue, post it for analysis.

Comment: @June7 Added some code, how can I make `bankAccounts` accessible via VBA Macros? I know I can add them to a new worksheet as cells, and then make the macro access the cells, but wondering if I can somehow as an object

Comment: @June7 and FYI I know how to write excel interop code, but all I need is a method that will do this. I have looked through the whole MSDN docs (Excel._Applicaiton, _Workbook, _Worksheet, and a few others) and could not find anything

Comment: You want this C# code modified to create bankAccounts as an object that VBA could grab and manipulate? No idea but I doubt it (withdraw my 'probably'). Maybe someone with C# experience will now offer an answer. What kind of object could bankAccounts be - array, recordset?

Comment: I can convert it into any C# object, that's not a problem, just need to find out how and what I can add to the excel VBA "object" graph